# How can I check the value of a string obtained via scripting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My Mac app gets 2 string values from another app via scripting. Under certain conditions, the sender supplies "0-1". I need to detect this and blank the text box that displays it. The following, which only shows code for the second string, works in the debugger, but not when run outside it.

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
// there was a change in a text control
int tmpInt2 = 0;
NSMutableString *tmp2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[inputTextField2 stringValue]];
//NSLog(@"text box changed. value: %i", val);
if ([tmp2 length] > 3)
{
    tmp2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[tmp2 substringToIndex:[tmp2 length] - 1]];
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:tmp2];
}
if ([tmp2 length] == 3)
{
    tmpInt2 = [tmp2 intValue];
    if (tmpInt2 > 360 || tmpInt2 < 0 || [tmp2 isEqualToString:@"0-1"])
    {
        //[self showAlert:@"Heading must be between 000 and 360"];
        [inputTextField2 setStringValue:@""];
        //[inputTextField2 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
        [tmp2 setString:@""];
    }
}
if ([[inputTextField2 stringValue] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"This is not a positive integer");
    //NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:tmp.length];
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:@""];
    //[[inputTextField2 cell] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
    [tmp2 setString:@""];
}
/*
if ([tmp2 isEqualToString:@"0-1"])
{
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:@""];
    [tmp2 setString:@""];
}
 */
if ([tmp2 rangeOfString:@"-"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain 0-1");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string contains 0-1!");
    [inputTextField2 setStringValue:@""];
    [tmp2 setString:@""];
}
```

}

Comment: I think you could do all that by implementing the code in a `NSFormatter` subclass and then associate the *formatter* with the text field.  I'm not sure it's such a good idea to make changes to the text field in a *change callback*, especially when a *formatter* provides this plumbing anyway.

Comment: I'm investigating it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into @trojanfoe's suggestion of using `NSFormatter` or one of its pre-defined subclasses. However you appear to misunderstand the purpose of `NSMutableString`, so I offer the following version of your code with some comments embedded. The text field used for the test was given a placeholder value of "Enter Heading", and it is assumed ARC is enabled. Modern property access syntax is used (object.property). HTH.

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // there was a change in a text control

   NSTextField *inputTextField = notification.object;   // get the field
   NSTextFieldCell *fieldCell = inputTextField.cell;    // and its cell - we use the placeholder text for feedback in this sample

   fieldCell.placeholderString = @"Enter heading";      // user has typed, restore default message

   NSString *contents = inputTextField.stringValue;     // an NSMutableString is not required, you never mutate this string
   NSUInteger length = contents.length;

   if (length > 3)
   {
      // remove last character - did you mean to truncate to three characters?
      inputTextField.stringValue = [contents substringToIndex:length - 1];
   }
   else if (length == 3)
   {
      int tmpInt = contents.intValue;
      if (tmpInt > 360 || tmpInt < 0 || [contents isEqualToString:@"0-1"])
      {
         fieldCell.placeholderString = @"Heading must be between 000 and 360"; // inform user why field was blanked             
         inputTextField.stringValue = @"";
      }
   }
   else if ([contents rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
   {
      // you might want different logic here
      // if a user types "12Y" you delete everything, deleting just the "Y" might be more friendly
      // ("Y" picked as an example as it could be a miss hit for the 6 or 7 keys)

      fieldCell.placeholderString = @"Enter a positive integer"; // inform user why field was blanked    
      inputTextField.stringValue = @"";
   }
}
```

**Addendum - Comment Followup**

Exactly what inputs you are expecting and what you wish to do with them is unclear. The first `if` just removes the last character from strings longer than 3 without doing any other checks. However I may have misinterpreted your intentions here, you have have intended to continue processing after that first `if`, e.g. something like:

```
...
   if (length > 3)
   {
      // remove last character - did you mean to truncate to three characters?
      contents = [contents substringToIndex:length - 1];
      length -= 1;
   }

   if (length == 3)
   {
      ...
```

Which means if your input is longer than 3 characters you remove the last (did you not want to simply truncate to 3? If so just change those two lines of code to do so) and then you continue with the following `if`/`else`.

Comment: Your code solved it, but I don't know why, I'm working on figuring that part out. The NSFormatter suggestion is another item on the study list. Coming from a Delphi background, I like the 'object.property' syntax.

Comment: My apologies, I spoke too soon. I'm still getting '0-1' displayed.

Comment: I suspect you are inputting something like `0-1` followed by a newline. I've added an addendum, but this may still not be what you are trying to do, e.g. `0-1xy` will be processed by the the second `if`'s `else` branch and so will produce a different message than `0-1x`. Only you know what inputs you need to handle and what you need to do with them.

Comment: The program that feeds mine via an Applescript calculates a 3 digit heading to a country, and if data is available, a 3 digit heading to a specific location within that country. If the location data is unavailable for the calculation, it emits '0-1'. Or at least that's what gets displayed in my text box. I'll check the length and see if it's a length issue. Both headings come in pretty much simultaneously. Since the code works in the debugger, I'm beginning to suspect a timing issue.

Comment: Progress! I moved the capture of both fields to the top of the method, before any processing. That seems to have done it.